# jQuery: How to subtract numeric values of each text input field in an array from that of a corresponding array?

Tags: jquery

I have two sets of of input fields like this, differentiated by their classes:

```
<div>
<input type="text" class="columnone" />
<input type="text" class="columnone" />
<input type="text" class="columnone" />
</div>

<div>
<input type="text" class="columntwo" />
<input type="text" class="columntwo" />
<input type="text" class="columntwo" />
</div>
```

Necessary validations are in place to ensure that only integer values can be input by the user into these fields.

How do I subtract the value of each input field in `.columntwo` from the value in the corresponding field in `.columnone` on `change()` in that particular `.columntwo` text field? Null values should be considered zero.

*For example, on `change()` in the first input field in `columntwo`, subtract the value of the first input field in `.columntwo` from the first field in `.columntwo`. Other fields remain unchanged.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you want to add the classes `columnone` and `columntwo` to the wrapping div,s instead of to each input element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit convoluted, but it will work. This works on the assumption that you want to trigger the function both ways (columntwo and columnone)

```
$('.columnone, .columntwo').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var sum = 0;
    var index = $this.index();

    if ($this.hasClass('columnone')) {
        var val1 = parseInt($this.val(), 10);
        var val2 = parseInt($('.columntwo:eq(' + index + ')').val(), 10);
    } else {
        var val2 = parseInt($this.val(), 10);
        var val1 = parseInt($('.columnone:eq(' + index + ')').val(), 10);
    }

    val1 = (isNaN(val1)) ? 0 : val1;
    val2 = (isNaN(val2)) ? 0 : val2;

    sum = val2 - val1;
    //console.log(sum);
    alert(sum);
});
```

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fJLAw/

Comment: @diEcho Yup, but I used parseInt because the OP mentioned integers.

Comment: When I use this, all `.columntwo` values are always being subtracted from the first input field of `.columnone`.

Comment: @Stroller do you mean in the fiddle or in your code? The fiddle works fine for me

Answer (score 3):

Under the assumption that you don't have any other elements with class columnone or columntwo, you can do

```
$('input.columntwo').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.val(parseInt($('input.columnone').eq($this.index()).val(),10) - parseInt($this.val(),10));
});
```

Comment: +1 for simple and fast solution . use `parseFloat` instead 'parseInt`

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't seem to be working when I prefix line 3 with 'var difference =' and then 'alert(difference);'